# Facing Issue when trying to disable HTTP methods in Production Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to disable the below HTTP methods in SharePoint web application config file but when I added below methods total site itself getting down some times I am getting 401 unauthorized access and access denied the issue . methods can be find below link Please find here Methods which i have used in web config.

Below are the methods tried to configure in web.config level.
[image: Http methods tried in web.config]

appreciate if anyone can help me on this

Comment: You most probably run some security scan that has flagged up some of the verbs available as vulnerability. For SP to work a lot of the verbs is required. Have a look for example on this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2019105/authentication-requests-when-you-open-office-documents

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
<deny verbs=“*” users=“*” />
```

You are denying All Users and All Verbs before the evaluation of the other statements in the xml (web.config is an xml file with a different file extension) thereby rendering them moot.

Also, sharepoint requires many of the other HTTP verbs you have set to deny.

Why are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.